# Is there any Android email app with advanced searching capability?

Tags: android, email, search

I have zillions of emails. I was suggested Bluemail app for Android but it sucks at searching.

I need to have something like Thunderbird has for desktops (no app, unfortunately) which allows me to do conditional searching such as: list me all the emails that contain the word "Minnie" only in the subject AND have CCed to "Mario" AND have an attachment.

Comment: Bluemail app was also found to [steal your passwords](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/blue-mail-android-mail-app-versendet-login-passwort-zum-e-mail-konto/), btw, so I'd rather not recommend it. I don't know which app has the search capabilities you're after, but you can check with [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_emailapps#group_400) while waiting for good recommendations. My recommendation would be avoiding those with trackers (monitor icons) and prefer those with stars (no tracking).

Answer (score 1):

I use **Fairmail** and love it.  The simple version is free, but I paid up for the **Pro** features.

Apart from the search features, you can set up comprehensive rules to move emails into folders, which makes the searches even easier.

> Main features
> Fully featured
> 100 % open source
> Privacy oriented
> Unlimited accounts
> Unlimited email addresses
> Unified inbox (optionally accounts or folders)
> Conversation threading
> Two way synchronization
> Offline storage and operations
> Battery friendly
> Low data usage
> Small (~25 MB)
> Material design (including dark/black theme)
> Maintained and supported

[Fairmail](https://email.faircode.eu/)

The search screen is

[image: Top half]

and

[image: Bottom Half]

Comment: I can confirm this works great. Nicely, it also supports in message searches, even if the emails are still in the server. This is apparently possible in some servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered/tried good ol' Gmail app?

You can search in it using all Gmail Search operators (see reference here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en). So you can use something like this: `subject:minnie has:attachment cc:minnie@example.com`

Comment: Does this work also for the mobile app or only for the desktop one? I cannot find any information. Also, can I add any account I want with the gmail mobile app?

Comment: @Millemila works (didn't use to, but does nowadays) for the Mobile App as well. Yes, you could add any email account to the Gmail app BUT... I do not know if the search will work the same way.

Comment: I need the search to work over multiple accounts. I will try it and get back here

Answer (score 0):

Check out Inbox by Blackberry. Allows to search multiple criteria and searches well.

Also has some great features like snoozing emails, gesture support, full editor, etc.
p.s. Free version displays a banner ad.